# PHP class method named print... not allowed?

Tags: php

I am writing a Controller for Codeigniter with a method named "print".  The name is important, because I would like to be able to access the page at "http://www.mysite.com/mycontroller/print".

However, I cannot do this because there is the syntax error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT, expecting T_STRING
```

Is there any special syntax to make the PHP interpreter "think" that when I say:

```
class MyClass extends Controller {
    function print() {
        // print method here
    }
}
```

... that I am talking about a method with a T_STRING name of "print" and not the T_PRINT that it is expecting it to be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't work because print is a [language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) in php. I know it looks like a function, but it is treated the same way as (for example) `function`, `while`, `include`, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

See the list of [Reserved Keywords in PHP](http://php.net/manual/reserved.keywords.php). You cannot use any of them as constants, class names, function or method names.

Answer (score 4):

I found that you can get around the naming restriction for *some* reserved words in `PHP 5.3` using the `__call` magic method.

```
public function __call( $name, $arguments )
{
  $fn = 'do_' . $name;
  if ( method_exists( $this, $fn ) )
  {
    return call_user_func_array( array( $this, fn), $arguments );
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception( 'Method "' . $name . '" does not exist.' );
  }
}

protected function do_print( /* $arg1, $arg2,...*/ )
{
  //whatever
}
```

I'm **not** saying this is necessarily a good idea, but it does allow you to make a call like `$foo->print()`.

I really see no reason *why* reserved words can't be used as method names for classes. I haven't been able to come up with an ambiguous case that would need to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

`print` like `echo` or `isset` are [language constructs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) and can not be used as function or classnames.

Answer (score 2):

If you called the print function 'hardcopy()' for example, you could use a mod-rewrite rule to accomplish the same thing.  ie:

RewriteRule ^/mycontroller/print /mycontroller/hardcopy [L]

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has pointed out, you can't use language constructs as function names.

Your solution is probably [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) so that you can use print in your url but something safe as your method name.